# How do I only show git info in the $PS1 if I am only in a git directory?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, git, zsh

I am using `oh-my-zsh` as my shell and I set up my `$PS1` in the `.zshrc` to be as follows:

```
PS1='[${SSH_CONNECTION+"%{$fg_bold[green]%}%n@%m:"}%{$fg_bold[blue]%}%c%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info)]$ '
```

This displays a prompt as so, if I am in a git directory:

`[Vortexgit:(master)]$`

I would like it to add a space before 'git' in the above prompt **only** when I am in a git directory.

For an example, see below:

Non-Git Directory: `[~]$`

Git Directory: `[Vortex git:(master)]$`

If I add a space before 'git' in my PS1 then the prompt in the non-git directory looks like this:

`[~ ]$`.

I don't want the space after th `~` in the above example. The space shouldn't be there when in a non-git directory. It should **only appear** if I am in a git-directory.

The modified `$PS1` that achieves `[~ ]$`:

```
PS1='[${SSH_CONNECTION+"%{$fg_bold[green]%}%n@%m:"}%{$fg_bold[blue]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)]$ '
```

Comment: [This tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-customize-your-command-prompt--net-24083) suggests changing the `ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX` environment variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Simply add this function and append it to the `$PS1` variable.

```
function put_spacing() {
  local git=$(git_prompt_info)
  local spacing=""
  if [ ${#git} != 0 ]; then
    spacing=" "
  else
    spacing=""
  fi

  echo $spacing
}

PS1='[${SSH_CONNECTION+"%{$fg_bold[green]%}%n@%m:"}%{$fg_bold[blue]%}%c%{$reset_color%}$(put_spacing)$(git_prompt_info)]$ '
```